# TypeError: LoginContract.LoginAttempt is not a function

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, nodejs

Here is my Login.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Login {
   event LoginAttempt(address sender, string challenge);

   function Login (string challenge) public {
       LoginAttempt(msg.sender, challenge);
   }

}
```

Here is my server.js

```
const LoginContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiLogin);

// LoginAttempt is the name of the event that signals logins in the
// Login contract. This is specified in the login.sol file.

loginAttempt = LoginContract.LoginAttempt({});

challenges = {};
successfulLogins = {};

loginAttempt.watch({}, '', function(error, event) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }

    console.log(event);

    const sender = event.args.sender.toLowerCase();

    // If the challenge sent through Ethereum matches the one we generated,
    // mark the login attempt as valid, otherwise ignore it.
    if(challenges[sender] === event.args.challenge) {
        successfulLogins[sender] = true;
    }
});
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code, I followed the instruction from https://auth0.com/blog/an-introduction-to-ethereum-and-smart-contracts-part-2/

But for some reason, my contract's event is unable to be watched. Can someone help me solve this issue?

**EDIT 1**
Since I need to deploy the contract, I changed my code above into these things below

```
let LoginContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiLogin);

web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount('6ded1c5b448819a6cde4293e33fbe54583ef5c52', 'bank')
.then(result => {
    util.log(`>>>>> contractApi - Is bank account unlocked ? ${result}`);
    util.log('>>>>> contractApi - Ready to deploy Login contract');

    LoginContract.deploy({
        data: '0x'+binLogin,
        arguments: ['']
    })
    .send({
        from: '6ded1c5b448819a6cde4293e33fbe54583ef5c52',
        gas: gas
    })
    .on('receipt', receipt => {
        util.log(`>>>>> contractApi - Login Contract sucessfully deployed @ address: ${receipt.contractAddress}`);
        // LoginAttempt is the name of the event that signals logins in the
        // Login contract. This is specified in the login.sol file.

        const loginContract = LoginContract.at(`${receipt.contractAddress}`)

        loginAttempt = loginContract.LoginAttempt();

        challenges = {};
        successfulLogins = {};

        loginAttempt.watch((error, event) => {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
                return;
            }

            console.log(event);

            const sender = event.args.sender.toLowerCase();

            // If the challenge sent through Ethereum matches the one we generated,
            // mark the login attempt as valid, otherwise ignore it.
            if(challenges[sender] === event.args.challenge) {
                successfulLogins[sender] = true;
            }
        });

        secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET || "my super secret passcode";

        util.log('>>>>> setup - Completed !!!')
    });
}, error => {
    util.log(`***** contractApi - Bank account unlock error - ${error}`);
});
```

But a new error occurs, **TypeError: LoginContract.at is not a function**. What should I do in this case? Does this issue related with web3 module installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a line which is also explained in the tutorial, and the most important:

```
const loginContract = LoginContract.at(process.env.LOGIN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS ||
                      '0xf7b06365e9012592c8c136b71c7a2475c7a94d71');
```

which this line you actually point at the contract instance in that specific address. You can get the contract address (0xf7...) when you deploy your contract (truffle might be helpful).

Comment: Hm I see, I'm not using truffle. 

What I did was deploying the contract manually, but the problem still persist, 
TypeError: LoginContract.at is not a function.

Comment: What version of web3 are you using?

Comment: How do you check web3 version ?

Comment: My web3 version is "web3@0.18.4"

Comment: then you don't need `new` to instance the contract:. just `let LoginContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiLogin);` and then `const contractInstance = LoginContract.at(address)`.  https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I realized how different are the web3 versions.

Comment: yes, sorry I actually forgot to remove the _new_ from my comment. copy paste issue.

Answer (score 1):

Code for Web3.js v 4.x.x (will also work for v 1.x.x)

```
const events = LoginContract.events.LoginAttempt();

events._emitter.on("connected", function(subscriptionId){
    console.log(subscriptionId);
})
.on('data', function(event){
    console.log(event); // same results as the optional callback above
    // If the challenge sent through Ethereum matches the one we generated,
    // mark the login attempt as valid, otherwise ignore it.
    const { sender, challenge } = event.returnValues;
    console.log(challenges);

    console.log('Sender:', sender);
    console.log('Challenge:', challenge);
    if(challenges[sender.toLowerCase()] === challenge) {
        successfulLogins[sender.toLowerCase()] = true;
    }
})
.on('error', function(error, receipt) { // If the transaction was rejected by the network with a receipt, the second parameter will be the receipt.
    console.log(error);
});
```

Also, the connection should be to a Web Socket, event listening is not available for HTTP provider

```
const { Web3, WebSocketProvider} = require('web3');
// Set up a connection to the Ganache network
const web3 = new Web3(new WebSocketProvider('ws://localhost:7545'));
```

here is the link to the web3.js docs

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth-contract.html#events